# SQL get difference between rows values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following code

```
SELECT MRT.sno, MRT.TypeName, MR.Adate, MAX(MRD.Value) AS Value
FROM MeterReadings MR 
INNER JOIN MeterReadingDetails MRD ON MRD.ReadingId = MR.sno
INNER JOIN MeterReadingTypes MRT ON MRT.sno = MRD.ReadingTypeId
WHERE MRT.sno IN (7,10,11)
GROUP BY MRT.sno,MRT.TypeName,MR.Adate
ORDER BY MR.Adate DESC
```

And result

```
sno TypeName                Adate                   Value

11  Toplam Kapasitif        2013-01-04 00:00:00     33,313
7   Toplam                  2013-01-04 00:00:00     7819,33
10  Toplam Reaktif          2013-01-04 00:00:00     640,492
11  Toplam Kapasitif        2013-01-03 00:00:00     33,276
7   Toplam                  2013-01-03 00:00:00     7805,934
10  Toplam Reaktif          2013-01-03 00:00:00     639,862
```

I want an additional column that named "OldValue". OldValue Column shows previous day value like following (last three row for above example)

```
33,276
7805,934
639,862
null
null
null
```

How Can I do this? There may be a similar example to show me the way.

Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE**

In fact, I wrote something like this

```
SELECT MRT.sno, MRT.TypeName, MR.Adate, MAX(MRD.Value) AS Value, 

(SELECT Value From
    (SELECT TOP 1 XMR.Adate,XMRD.ReadingTypeId,MAX(XMRD.Value) AS Value 
    FROM MeterReadings XMR,MeterReadingDetails XMRD 
    WHERE XMRD.ReadingId = XMR.sno AND XMRD.ReadingTypeId = MRT.sno AND XMR.Adate<MR.Adate 
    GROUP BY XMR.Adate,XMRD.ReadingTypeId 
    ORDER BY XMR.Adate DESC) AS TBL
) AS OldValue

FROM MeterReadings MR 
INNER JOIN MeterReadingDetails MRD ON MRD.ReadingId = MR.sno
INNER JOIN MeterReadingTypes MRT ON MRT.sno = MRD.ReadingTypeId
WHERE MRT.sno IN (7,10,11)
GROUP BY MRT.sno,MRT.TypeName,MR.Adate
```

But I dont know, Is this best way?

Comment: Is it right that you use `MAX(MRD.Value)`? In general it doesn't relate to `MR.Adate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'r using SQL Server 2012, you could use the new [`LAG` analytical function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/)

> SQL Server 2012 introduces new analytical function LEAD() and LAG().
>   This functions accesses data from a subsequent row (for lead) and
>   previous row (for lag) in the same result set without the use of a
>   self-join .

Your statement then becomes

```
SELECT  *, LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY sno ORDER BY Adate DESC)
FROM    (
          SELECT  MRT.sno, MRT.TypeName, MR.Adate, MAX(MRD.Value) AS Value, 
          FROM    MeterReadings MR 
                  INNER JOIN MeterReadingDetails MRD ON MRD.ReadingId = MR.sno
                  INNER JOIN MeterReadingTypes MRT ON MRT.sno = MRD.ReadingTypeId
          WHERE   MRT.sno IN (7,10,11)
          GROUP BY
                  MRT.sno,MRT.TypeName,MR.Adate
        ) q
ORDER BY
        Adate DESC
```

Using SQL Server 2005/2008, I would write the statement as

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  MRT.sno, MRT.TypeName, MR.Adate, MAX(MRD.Value) AS Value, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MRT.sno ORDER BY MR.Adate DESC)
  FROM    MeterReadings MR 
          INNER JOIN MeterReadingDetails MRD ON MRD.ReadingId = MR.sno
          INNER JOIN MeterReadingTypes MRT ON MRT.sno = MRD.ReadingTypeId
  WHERE   MRT.sno IN (7,10,11)
  GROUP BY
          MRT.sno,MRT.TypeName,MR.Adate
)
SELECT  q1.*, q2.Value
FROM    q q1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN q q2 ON q2.sno = q1.sno AND q2.rn = q1.rn + 1
```

**Edit**

The main difference between using either one of these solutions to yours is that your solution has to retrieve the previous result **for each** record, an expensive operation, while this solutions in essence can join two complete (identical) sets of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cant understand your code yet, But it works better than mine.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi - Are you using SQL Server 2012 or 2005/2008?

Comment: What's the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: There is no problem about your codes. I m new about sql, so I cant understand fully your codes. I m examining your codes now.

Comment: If you get stuck on some part, you're free to ask.